# How to adapt a GROUP BY across multiple tables?

Tags: sql, database, toad

I'm trying to optimize a SQL query that uses a `GROUP BY` across multiple tables. Essentially, I have multiple tables which all contain a PID column, and the output I need is a record of every PID in all of the tables as well as a count of how many records across all of those tables contain that PID. When trying to use `GROUP BY PID`, I get a "column ambiguously defined" error if using multiple tables. Here is an example of the code I am using to retrieve the proper data from one table (can ignore the where clause):

```
select pid, count(*)
from table1
where vendor_id in(1,2)
    and delay_code <=23
    and age between 18 and 49 and sex = 'M'
group by pid
```

Essentially, I want to do this across a group of tables (i.e. table1, table2, table3 etc), but can't figure out how to do so without getting a "column ambiguously defined" error.

Comment: Don't tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. I have removed the conflicting tags.

Comment: Also, your question says you are doing this for multiple tables, but your query only references one, not many. Show us the attempt that *isn't* working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify what record you are referencing.  You can do that either by specifying the table, or using an alias.  Aliases are required when you have multiple references to the same table.

Specify table:

```
SELECT table1.pid, COUNT(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY table1.pid
```

Use alias:

```
SELECT t1.pid, COUNT(*)
FROM table1 AS t1
GROUP BY t1.pid
```